# Movable UIButtons

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uibutton

**Scenario**:
There is an UIView as a sub view of a UIScrollView and there is a UIImageView as a sub view of the UIView.

**Requirement**:
When the user touches on the UIImageView I want to add a UIButton as a sub view at that touch point. Any amount of UIButtons could be added (Within the UIImageView frame). These UIButtons should also be movable inside the UIImageView frame.

**What I have done**
I have sub classed the UIView and I'm detecting touches using methods touchesBegan, touchesMoved, touchesEnded and adding UIButtons. UIButtons are added with UIGestureRecognizers with a method implemented to the pan gesture.

**Problem**
When I add more than one button the earlier ones becomes non-movable and doesn't even recognise touch up inside.

Comment: You don't list requirements on SOF, you ask questions. Where is your question?

Comment: @dealock Sorry about that. Please have a look now. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for the help. I ended up doing this https://github.com/Tulakshana/TTaggableView

Answer (score 0):

You should read about Gesture Recognizers:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html

http://www.raywenderlich.com/6567/uigesturerecognizer-tutorial-in-ios-5-pinches-pans-and-more

Start with UITapGestureRecognizer for showing UIButtons.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I ended up doing this https://github.com/Tulakshana/TTaggableView